# How can I tell when a screen is shown in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple Tab bar navigation app

```
-------------------
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|       (o)       |
|                 |
[ Tab 1 ]_[ Tab 2 ]
```

When Tab 1 is touched, Screen 1 is shown. When Tab 2 is pressed, Screen 2 is shown.

How can I call an action each time a screen is shown (not just on the `viewDidLoad` event).

Do I have to listen to the touch event on the Tab bar or is there an event in the ViewController I can listen for?

Comment: "When Tab 1 is touched, Screen 1 is shown. When Tab 2 is pressed, Screen 2 is shown?" Yes it is.

Comment: *is there an event in the ViewController I can listen for?* What did you find when you looked at the [documentation for UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` gets called when the nib is being *loaded* into memory. When a view is actually *appearing* on the screen, `viewDidAppear` gets called.

[Edit]

This is the (natural) order of callbacks: 
`initWithNibName:Bundle: -> awakeFromNib -> loadView -> viewDidLoad -> viewWillAppear -> viewDidAppear`

[Edit2]

see here for an excellent explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109277/347353

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`viewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16) and [`viewDidAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW17).

1. `viewWillAppear`

   > Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy.
2. `viewDidAppear`

   > Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy.

Comment: I know — you had the correct quotes but swapped over. I just swapped them back :)

Comment: @Amorya - I just swapped them too at the same moment as you :) Thanks.

Comment: Ah, all's well that ends well. Good answer btw.