# Setting delegate to MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, mkmapview, viewcontroller

I am new to iOS programming. I have created ViewController with MKMapView element, and I wanted to set delegate `[mapView setDelegate:self]`

First I done it in method initWithNibName:bundle: like:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {  
        [[self map] setDelegate:self]];
        UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
        [item setTitle:@"Map"];
        [self setTabBarItem:item];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In this case MKMapView did not send me any messages, but when I placed setting delegate message to `viewDidLoad` method, it worked fine.

Could someone explain me why it was not working when `setting delegate message` was in `initWithNibName:bundle`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views do not get loaded in `initWithNibName`, it just initializes your viewcontroller class and load the xib file which contains your view details.

When viewcontroller calls `viewDidLoad`, you will have all your view objects allocated and initialized.

In your case, when you `setDelegate` in `initWithNibname`, you are calling it on a   nil value, so nothing get set, but in `viewDidLoad` mapView is allocated and initialized, so it works fine.

For a deeper insight refer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Beautiful explanation here: [What is the process of a UIViewController birth (which method follows which)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107604/can-somebody-explain-the-process-of-a-uiviewcontroller-birth-which-method-follo)

[Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)

http://thejoeconwayblog.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/view-controller-lifecycle-in-ios-6/

[image: View Life-cycle]

Comment: Tnx a lot. So now I know when viewcontroller objects become initialized =)

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

> [self map]

In `initWithNibName` the map is not yet initialized and it returns nil.

In `viewDidLoad` the map is already initialized.