# What's the proper way to indicate loading activity on UITableView on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I know that I can use [`SVProgressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) any time I need to show user that something is being loaded on the whole screen.

However, is there a conventional way to show an activity indicator or spinner inside `UITableView` in iOS 7 design guidelines. I think SVProgressHUD is just ugly in iOS 7 and I thought there must be a better solution.

What is the Apple way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The apple way of doing this is by showing activity indicator on top of table view.

You can check the Native Mail application for the its working.

[image: Mail App]

Implementation -

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

You can start/stop refreshing using these methods.

– beginRefreshing
– endRefreshing

Comment: To elaborate a little further with this, check out the accepted answer on [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930730/uirefreshcontrol-on-viewdidload) as it gives a full example.

Answer (score 0):

I thought a while about this one as well and came up with the following solution:

By utilizing the table view's `backgroundView` property, you can set a dedicated background view which can be styled the way you want it.

1. Create an UIViewController in the Storyboard and style the view it the way you want. My suggestion: An UIActivityIndicatorView and an UILabel centered both horizontally and vertically.
2. Set a storyboard ID for the view controller.
3. In the `viewDidLoad` method paste the following code which assigns the created view to the table view's background. Make sure you set replace the identifier with whatever you set it to earlier.

   ```
   self.tableView.backgroundView = ((UIViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourStoryboardID"]).view;
   self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   ```
4. Whenever you are ready to hide the loading view, just do the following:

   ```
   self.tableView.backgroundView.hidden = YES;
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: From the documentation for tableView.backgroundView: "You must set this property to nil to set the background color of the table view."