# UITableview getting flickering with UIRefreshcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

When I remove all object from tableview and with animation reload tableview at that time tableview getting flicker.

I am doing something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.voiceSTableView.voicestationDelegate = self;

    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(getRefreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];

    tableViewController.tableView = self.voiceSTableView ;

    tableViewController.refreshControl = refreshControl;

    self.voiceSTableView.refreshController = refreshControl;


}

-(void)getRefreshData{

    if(isRequestLoading){
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
        return;
    }
    [self.voiceSTableView.arVoicerData removeAllObjects];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
        [self.voiceSTableView reloadData];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
 }
```

even this code also not working :

```
[self.voiceSTableview reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: Remove your all objects from array one's you got the response from the server. Don't delete in getRefreshData method.

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya I try your solution but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have also face same issue earlier.

Please try with this link:

"[UIRefreshControl on viewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930730/uirefreshcontrol-on-viewdidload)"