# Reusable Nibs in Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I'm looking for a way to make nibs that I can then embed and reuse inside a storyboard with all the `IBOutlets` correctly instantiated. I was able to get it working using a modified version of [this tutorial](http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2014/09/ios-creating-reusable-uiviews-with-storyboard-part-2/).

The steps for getting this to work are:

1. Make a custom view subclass and corresponding nib
2. Set `File's Owner` to the custom view subclass
3. Add a `UIView` as a direct descendent of the nib's view (this is our Content View)
4. Create an `IBOutlet` in your view class called `contentView` of type `UIView` and content the content view in the nib to that outlet
5. In `awakeFromNib` do the following:

   ```
   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib() //call super
       NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: self, options: nil)
       self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.addSubview(self.contentView)

       self.addEdgeConstraintWithAttribute(.Left, withSubview: self.contentView)
       self.addEdgeConstraintWithAttribute(.Top, withSubview: self.contentView)
       self.addEdgeConstraintWithAttribute(.Right, withSubview: self.contentView)
       self.addEdgeConstraintWithAttribute(.Bottom, withSubview: self.contentView)
   }
   ```

This process works fine but I don't understand HOW works. And is there a better way of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all magic comes from the `awakeFromNib` from `NSNibAwaking` protocol.

> "The `-awakeFromNib` method is called for every object that is
>   instantiated when a nib file is loaded..." - [e.James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109277/593709)

Lets say, you made a class and nib with the name of `MyView` and done all the above steps, Now when you add a `UIView` in your storyboard and set its class to `MyView` and run the app. Here's what happens.

- You storyboard loads all views and also calls `awakeFromNib` for your
  `MyView`.
- Your `awakeFromNib` then triggers the loading of nib named `MyView`.
- You get the content view from Nib instantiated views and add it to storyboard instantiated view and set its constraints.
- Notice the `loadNibNamed` method, you're sending `self` as owner, so 
  when the nib is unarchived and loaded, it sets all the `IBOutlets` to
  the sent `self`, that's why your `IBOutlet` worked i.e `self.contentView` because contentView now has view from nib.

Comment: Are two different view instances getting loaded or rather is it two different nibs (one from the storyboard, one from the nib) that then get the `IBOutlet` properties merged together?

Comment: Yes. There's one and that's from storyboard. It had nothing initially as subviews, so it loaded the nib so it could load its subviews. I've edited it to make it less confusing.