# iOS: Which function to override when I need to do something after the view is visible to the user?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So the first thing my app does is get a list of movies from an API. I'm trying to handle if there's a network issue. Currently, in my viewDidLoad method, I call "updateApiInfo", which contains the following code:

```
if self.movies == nil {
            print("stuff went wrong")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Network Error", message: "There was a nework error.\nYou must be connected to the internet to use Flicks.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Exit", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in
                UIControl().sendAction(Selector("suspend"), to: UIApplication.sharedApplication(), forEvent: nil)
            }))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When viewDidLoad calls updateApiInfo, I get this message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fad10e3ad80> on <Flicks.MoviesViewController: 0x7fad10e35cc0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

When I call updateApiInfo just from the user refreshing, the error pops up as expected.

I'm assuming that viewDidLoad only gets called *before* the view gets displayed to the user, which I guess is causing this error. Is there a method I can stick this code in for *after* the view is displayed to the user, so the problem can presumably get fixed?

Comment: No, `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is instantiated, but before it is presented. You'd generally use `viewDidAppear` for stuff after the view is actually presented.

Comment: That's right. `viewDidLoad()` only guarantees that the view controller's main view is instantiated (and any subviews defined in Interface Builder, too).

Comment: @CaptainForge - did my answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `viewDidAppear:` to make sure the view is already in the window hierarchy.

There's a pretty good explanation of the order in which the methods are called here:
[What is the process of a UIViewController birth (which method follows which)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107604/can-somebody-explain-the-process-of-a-uiviewcontroller-birth-which-method-follo)