# What is the Call Order of iOS UIViewController Delegate Methods, specifically viewDidLoad through viewDidAppear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I looked around SO long enough to not find a readily available and absolutely relevant answer to this question, so I am asking for those who have and may, in the future, do the same.

So.. What is the call Order of iOS UIViewController delegate methods, specifically viewDidLoad through viewDidAppear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)

Comment: This has been asked many times man...dont need to create just to answer it yourself

Comment: I guess I did not look hard enough. Tried to delete but somebody else answered it before i could.

Answer (score 0):

The call order for viewDidLoad through viewDidAppear is as follows:

1. loadView
2. viewDidLoad
3. viewWillAppear
4. viewDidAppear

For the full lifecyle of an iOS UIViewController, you may find this diagram useful: https://rdkw.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/

Answer (score 0):

The flow might be changed according to the scenario you're having. Overall possible ways the UIViewController gets invoked is shown below.
[image]

Please find this for more explanations: [Detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109277/5215474)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14367458)

Comment: @Shivaay Have added diagram showing the same. Thank you for review.